# dismiss UIPopOverController from contentViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

How can you dismiss a popover from the contentViewController, so in the example code I have below I would like to dismiss the UIPopOver from the ProfileViewController code. How do I do this? Another post similar to this suggested to use NSNotification, but how do use it?

```
- (void)profilePop:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    ProfileViewController * profile = [[ProfileViewController alloc] init];
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.table];
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.table indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    ConvoreCell* cell = (ConvoreCell *) [self.table cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    profile.uid =  [[[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] creator] mid];
    UIPopoverController * profilePop  = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:profile];
    [profilePop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(350, 180)];
    [profilePop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0, cell.avatar.frame.size.width, cell.avatar.frame.size.height) inView:cell permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep a reference to the popover in your profile class.

```
profile.popOver = profilePop;
```

then in the area you'de like to dismiss:

```
[self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: This is probably the way to go. There are many other cases where you'll want to send other messages from the content view controller to the first view controller, so this is a good pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think keeping a reference is the way to go too, but I don't know if its a good idea to retain it, because when you need to release the popover controller it won't dealloc because there is an extra retain.